# WCF Data Service: How to return custom class object

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

Hi i want to return a custom class object from wcf data service.

my req is that i have a class A which contains some property along with a list property of other class B.
i want to return the object of class b.

plz help

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data on the server as in-memory classes, you can use reflection provider to expose them as WCF Data Service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723653.aspx